# sqlite How to add another subqueries?

Tags: sqlite

I have in sqlite query:

```
   DELETE FROM test
      WHERE a NOT IN (
            SELECT * FROM (
                   SELECT MAX(a) FROM test GROUP BY z )
                     )
```

It is working ok. Problem begins if there is another line with the same 'a' max value. In this case none of lines are deleted.
How to add another condition (subqueries) - when are two the same max values, number from column b determines what of line should be deleted ?

Comment: I don't think you can use `WHERE IN` for this query on SQLite.  It might have been possible on other databases, such as MySQL, which support tuple syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the rows with the max `a` for each `z` and delete the others then you can use `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM test t
  WHERE t.z = test.z AND a > test.a
)
```

Or with a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE a < (SELECT MAX(t.a) FROM test t WHERE t.z = test.z)
```

Or by using [`ROW VALUES`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) with the operator `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE (z, a) NOT IN (SELECT z, MAX(a) FROM test GROUP BY z)
```

Edit:

If you have another column `b` that resolves the ties in case there are more than 1 rows with the same max `a` then use also `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` window function:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE (z, a, b) IN (
  SELECT z, a, b
  FROM (
    SELECT z, a, b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY z ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC) rn
    FROM test
  ) t
  WHERE rn > 1  
)
```

Or delete all the rows with `rowid` different than the `rowid` with the max `a` (and max `b` if there are ties) for each `z`:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE rowid <> (SELECT t.rowid FROM test t WHERE t.z = test.z ORDER BY t.a DESC, t.b DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Or with `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM test t
  WHERE (t.z = test.z) AND (t.a > test.a OR (t.a = test.a AND t.b > test.b))
);
```

Comment: It works if I have: 
1 line: a=10, b=5, z=ppp ;
2 line: a=20, b=4, z=ppp ;
after query '2 line: a=20, b=4, z=ppp' only left. ;

Problem is when there are:
1 line: a=10, b=5, z=ppp ;
2 line: a=10, b=4, z=ppp ;
'a' is the same, and after query nothing is deleted, but line 2nd should be deleted.

Comment: This comment should be insid your question to clarify the requirement. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank You. Last one code works, but  is it possible that for big db it takes a lot of time ? I run it in SQLiteStudio. Your first code (after EDIT) show me "near "(": syntax error" I tired to correct it using sqlitetutorial site where is about RANK, and PARTITION but without success :(

Comment: You can see here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jvUzVqdJjpy9514JFS1w51/0 the query is syntactically correct. Maybe you are using an old version of SQLite that does not support window functions which are very efficient. If this is the case then I'm afraid you will have to use less performant solutions.

Comment: Check my last query.

Comment: It is work for small database. I run it on db where is 400,000 rows and it has been working for 1 hour and has not finished yet. My SQLite version is 3.31.1 on ubuntu.

Comment: SQLite 3.31.0 supports window functions so you can use ROW_NUMBER(). If you are getting an error then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: In sqlite console it is working ok and really fast. Problem was with my SqliteStudio.